# Fill a cell based on the value in another

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to fill one cell with a specific value based on the value in another cell. For instance, If A1 has a value of 0 to 500, B1 is 10. If A1 has a value of 501 to 1000, B1 IS 25. If A1 has a value of 1001 to 1500, B1 IS 40. If A1 has a value of 1500+, B1 IS 50. So on and so forth. I tried using the IF function but I may not be doing it right. I have the newest edition of Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your case can be resolved by nesting multiple `IF` function. Try the following formula on cell B1:

```
=IF(A1<501,10,IF(A1<1001,25,IF(A1<1501,40,50)))
```

[image]

Comment: This worked beautifully! Thank You!

Comment: @DavidDuran Follow the [Tour](https://superuser.com/tour) and also [this](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers) to learn how ti say thanks on this site.

Answer (score 0):

I like this way:

```
=XLOOKUP(A2:A16,{0,500,1000,1500},{10,25,40,50},"",-1)
```

The good thing about this is you can add as many lookup items to the arrays as you want. Nesting IF statements will have a limit.

Put that in the first cell where you want the formulas - it will spill down (adjust the first parameter to be the length of your range):

[image]

But this is also good:

```
=IFS(A2:A16<500,10,A2:A16<1000,25,A2:A16<1500,40,TRUE,50)
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering you might want to add some keys and corresponding values in the future, I suggest that you first [create a table](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-and-format-tables-e81aa349-b006-4f8a-9806-5af9df0ac664) with 2 columns - keys and values. 
Should look Like this:

[image]

Then, [rename the table](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/rename-an-excel-table-fbf49a4f-82a3-43eb-8ba2-44d21233b114) to an any meaningful name (e.g. tableKeys) and use XLOOKUP wherever you want to get the value of a key.

For example, this is how you would get the value of a key stored in A1:

```
=XLOOKUP(A1,tableKeys[Key],tableKeys[Value],"",-1)
```